# IIS7 Folder Name - Is the "+" character valid?

Tags: javascript, html, iis-7, invalid-characters

I'm attempting to create a Google Plus redirect like this...
www.domain.com/+

I have created a folder named "+" with a simple default.html file inside. Default.html is a default document and it contains a simple JS redirect. I get a 404 like the folder and file do not exist. Very strange!

The plus character [appears to be valid](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joelo/archive/2007/06/27/file-name-length-size-and-invalid-character-restrictions-and-recommendations.aspx) for folder names so I'm stumped. 
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Just curious, does `www.domain.com/%2B` work?

Comment: And, can you access say, a "Hello World" HTML file in said `+` folder? (e.g. does this question really have anything to do with either JavaScript or HTML?)

Comment: .../%2b didn't work and it is currently setup as hello world for troubleshooting. No luck yet. You're right about the js and html tags. I was enjoying the tag adding process a little too much I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a nice 301 redirect in a web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
    <location path="+">
        <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://plus.google.com/{userprofileid}" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Edit: I allowed double escaping which disables IIS7's interpolation of a + as a space.  Solution obtained from: http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/entryid/60/404-error-in-iis-7-when-using-a-url-with-a-plus-sign-in-the-path

Comment: I may end up using this or a URL rewrite, but I was hoping to share a simple technique for the technically challenged.

Comment: Fair enough.  I wish I knew of the server-side answer to your dilemma.  Thanks for the +1.

Comment: The oshineye.com/+ example works with JS disabled so maybe it can only be done with web.config or equivalent technique. Asking Google this question proved difficult given the keywords involved.

Comment: Go to http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php and input "oshineye.com/+"

He is definitely using a 301 redirect on the server side.

Comment: Upon further investigation, the above 301 redirect does not work. It is simply ignored. URL Rewrite 2 does not work either. I'm starting to believe this is an IIS limitation. Using the tool you mentioned above I determined that oshineye.com is an Apache server. Unfortunately I don't have access to an apache server to test :-(

Comment: @JoeHakooz: Notice the edit I made above.  This turns off IIS7 escaping, including the interpolation of a + as a space.  This should work for you, but read the source link above for potential security issues.

Comment: Booyah! Nailed it Jason. Thanks again. One note... the system.webserver node should be inside the configuration node.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS7, by default, + is often times interpolated as a space.  IIS7 may allow for folders named +, but the URL processor is interpolating it first to a space.

See http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/entryid/60/404-error-in-iis-7-when-using-a-url-with-a-plus-sign-in-the-path for a workaround, but this potentially opens up security flaws.